# Weighted Pie Chart Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a weighted pie chart using pandas. Here is a simple example to build off of.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['red', 10], ['orange', 15], ['blue', 14], ['red', 8], 
        ['orange', 11], ['blue', 20]]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['color', 'weight'])
```

Comment: Please be specific when posing your question. Please refer the [ask] page.

Comment: Hi and welcome Nate. Please note that everybody here is happy to help, but this is about support and not about letting other code for you. Post what you already have tried or what you're problem is. For me it seems like you haven't even googled. The second result gives you all answers you need: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to create a new "totals" column and create the pie chart from there.

```
new_df = df.groupby(['color'])[['weight']].sum()
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
new_df.columns = ['color', 'total']
```

From there I prefer to use plotly express

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.pie(new_df, values='total', names='color', title='...')
```